# how to use lsqcurvefit in MatLab to solve integer constrained nonlinear inversion?

Tags: matlab, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to use lsqcurvefit in MatLab to solve a problem like this:
x=lsqcurvefit(@myfun,x0,xdata,ydata) where x can only be integer.
It seems that the default setting makes x change in a way that goes over any kind of value.
Could anyone be so nice to help?